# how do you extract data from nested json file and create a data frame in python

Tags: python, json, dataframe

I have this nested json data:

```
    {
  "result": [
    {
    "deviceid": 33,
    "devicename": "server101",
    "objectName": "CPU",
    "data": [
    {
      "value":0.59,
      "rvalue":null
    },
    {
      "value":90,
      "rvalue":null
    },
    {
      "value": 85,
      "rvalue":null
    }
          ]
  },
  {
  "deviceid": 30,
    "devicename": "server10",
    "objectName": "CPU",
    "data": [
    {
      "value":0.30,
      "rvalue":null
    },
    {
      "value":60,
      "rvalue":null
    },
    {
      "value": 79,
      "rvalue":null
    }
    ]
  },
  {
  "deviceid": 0,
    "devicename": "server300",
    "objectName": "CPU",
    "data": [
    {
      "value":0.10,
      "rvalue":null
    },
    {
      "value":0.20,
      "rvalue":null
    },
    {
      "value": 0.25,
      "rvalue:":null
    }]
  }
  ],
  "timeRanges": [
    {
      "name":"1st Month",
      "startTime":1680000000,
      "endTime": 1689000000
    },
    {
      "name":"2nd Month",
      "startTime": 1680000000,
      "endTime": 1689000000
    },
    {
      "name":"3rd Month",
      "startTime": 1680000000,
      "endTime": 1689000000 
    }
  ]
}
```

I need to extract data from this json and append to a data frame.

The output should be like this:

```
deviceid deviceName objectName 1stMonth 2ndMonth 3rdMonth. startTime. endTime
33      server101  CPU      0.59     90      85       1680000000  1689000000
30      server10   CPU      0.30     60      79      1680000000  1689000000
0       server300  CPU      0.10     0.20    0.25     1680000000  1689000000
```

I am very new to this and would appreciate any guidance.

Comment: Check the pandas documentation, especially the pandas DataFrame user guide, [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/dsintro.html#from-dict-of-series-or-dicts) might be a good starting point as it describes how to create a DataFrame from data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code below seems to produce the desired result. I converted `null` to `"null"`. However, as mentioned in the comments below, Python can recognise the `null` value using `json.loads()`

```
import pandas as pd

adict =    {
  "result": [
    {
    "deviceid": 33,
    "devicename": "server101",
    "objectName": "CPU",
    "data": [
    {
      "value":0.59,
      "rvalue":"null"
    },
    {
      "value":90,
      "rvalue":"null"
    },
    {
      "value": 85,
      "rvalue":"null"
    }
          ]
  },
  {
  "deviceid": 30,
    "devicename": "server10",
    "objectName": "CPU",
    "data": [
    {
      "value":0.30,
      "rvalue":"null"
    },
    {
      "value":60,
      "rvalue":"null"
    },
    {
      "value": 79,
      "rvalue":"null"
    }
    ]
  },
  {
  "deviceid": 0,
    "devicename": "server300",
    "objectName": "CPU",
    "data": [
    {
      "value":0.10,
      "rvalue":"null"
    },
    {
      "value":0.20,
      "rvalue":"null"
    },
    {
      "value": 0.25,
      "rvalue:":"null"
    }]
  }
  ],
  "timeRanges": [
    {
      "name":"1st Month",
      "startTime":1680000000,
      "endTime": 1689000000
    },
    {
      "name":"2nd Month",
      "startTime": 1680000000,
      "endTime": 1689000000
    },
    {
      "name":"3rd Month",
      "startTime": 1680000000,
      "endTime": 1689000000 
    }
  ]
}

rows = []
for ind in range(len(adict["result"])):
    row = [adict["result"][ind]["deviceid"] , adict["result"][ind]["devicename"], 
           adict["result"][ind]["objectName"],  
           adict["result"][ind]["data"][0]["value"],  adict["result"][ind]["data"][1]["value"], 
           adict["result"][ind]["data"][2]["value"], 
           adict["timeRanges"][ind]["startTime"],  adict["timeRanges"][ind]["endTime"]
          ]
    rows.append(row)

column_names = ["deviceid", "deviceName", "objectName", "1stMonth",
                "2ndMonth", "3rdMonth", "startTime", "endTime"]
df = pd.DataFrame(data = rows, columns=column_names)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   deviceid deviceName objectName  1stMonth  2ndMonth  3rdMonth   startTime     endTime
0        33  server101        CPU      0.59      90.0     85.00  1680000000  1689000000
1        30   server10        CPU      0.30      60.0     79.00  1680000000  1689000000
2         0  server300        CPU      0.10       0.2      0.25  1680000000  1689000000
```

I have attached the actual json file here:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I am getting this error "IndexError: list index out of range"

Comment: Sounds like you're inputting a different json object, if I knew the structure it might be possible to generalise the above approach.

Comment: I have attached the json file

Comment: You say, *I had to convert null to "null" as Python didn't recognise the null value.* I beg to differ. See [this](https://ideone.com/KTlk5M).

Comment: @user1471980 I can't download your JSON attachment, is this a JPG image? or a text or JSON file. If I can download I can try to parse it locally

Answer (score 2):

After fixing some *typos* in your `json` file, you can use :

```
with open("file.json") as file:
    obj = json.load(file)

df = (
    pd.json_normalize(
        obj["result"], "data", ["deviceid", "devicename", "objectName"])
        .join(pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(obj["timeRanges"])]*len(obj["result"]),
             ignore_index=True)).pivot(
        index=["deviceid", "devicename", "objectName", "startTime", "endTime"],
        columns="name", values="value").reset_index().rename_axis(None, axis=1)
)
```

Output :

```
print(df.to_string(index=False))

 deviceid devicename objectName  startTime    endTime  1st Month  2nd Month  3rd Month
        0  server300        CPU 1680000000 1689000000       0.10       0.20       0.25
       30   server10        CPU 1680000000 1689000000       0.30      60.00      79.00
       33  server101        CPU 1680000000 1689000000       0.59      90.00      85.00
```

Comment: I am getting this error ValueError: Length of passed values is 30, index implies 5.

Comment: With the given *json-file/example* in your post, the code throws no error.

Comment: when I do print(type(obj)), it says ",class 'dict'> ", is this the issue you think?

Comment: No, the error means that you provided an example that does not match with your real dataset.

Comment: I have attached the actual json file

Answer (score 0):

I feel like I'm missing something due to your json and/or structure...but this provides the results you requested.

```
import pandas as pd

# CLEAN THE PAYLOAD
null = None

# WHAT YOU PROVIDED
json = {
  "result": [
    {
    "deviceid": 33,
    "devicename": "server101",
    "objectName": "CPU",
    "data": [
    {
      "value":0.59,
      "rvalue":null
    },
    {
      "value":90,
      "rvalue":null
    },
    {
      "value": 85,
      "rvalue":null
    }
          ]
  },
  {
  "deviceid": 30,
    "devicename": "server10",
    "objectName": "CPU",
    "data": [
    {
      "value":0.30,
      "rvalue":null
    },
    {
      "value":60,
      "rvalue":null
    },
    {
      "value": 79,
      "rvalue":null
    }
    ]
  },
  {
  "deviceid": 0,
    "devicename": "server300",
    "objectName": "CPU",
    "data": [
    {
      "value":0.10,
      "rvalue":null
    },
    {
      "value":0.20,
      "rvalue":null
    },
    {
      "value": 0.25,
      "rvalue:":null
    }]
  }
  ],
  "timeRanges": [
    {
      "name":"1st Month",
      "startTime":1680000000,
      "endTime": 1689000000
    },
    {
      "name":"2nd Month",
      "startTime": 1680000000,
      "endTime": 1689000000
    },
    {
      "name":"3rd Month",
      "startTime": 1680000000,
      "endTime": 1689000000 
    }
  ]
}






df = pd.DataFrame(json)
results = pd.json_normalize(df["result"], "data", ["deviceid", "devicename", "objectName"])
times = pd.json_normalize(df["timeRanges"]).drop(columns=['name'])
trans = results.pivot_table(index=["deviceid", "devicename", "objectName"],values='value',aggfunc=list).squeeze()
data = pd.DataFrame(trans.tolist(),index=trans.index,columns=['1stMonth','2ndMonth','3rdMonth.']).reset_index()
final = pd.concat([data, times], axis=1)

print(final)
```

Output:

```
deviceid devicename objectName  1stMonth  2ndMonth  3rdMonth.   startTime     endTime
0         0  server300        CPU      0.10       0.2       0.25  1680000000  1689000000
1        30   server10        CPU      0.30      60.0      79.00  1680000000  1689000000
2        33  server101        CPU      0.59      90.0      85.00  1680000000  1689000000
```

Comment: this line is returning error "df=pd.DataFrame(json) "ValueError: arrays must all be same lenght"

Comment: That should basically be the nested json you provided in your initial post

Comment: I added the json, you should now receive the output. Try again.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the json library to parse the json if it's a string.

```
import json
import pandas as pd

json_data = '''
{
  "result": [
    {
      "deviceid": 33,
      "devicename": "server101",
      "objectName": "CPU",
      "data": [
        {
          "value":0.59,
          "rvalue":null
        },
        {
          "value":90,
          "rvalue":null
        },
        {
          "value": 85,
          "rvalue":null
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "deviceid": 30,
      "devicename": "server10",
      "objectName": "CPU",
      "data": [
        {
          "value":0.30,
          "rvalue":null
        },
        {
          "value":60,
          "rvalue":null
        },
        {
          "value": 79,
          "rvalue":null
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "deviceid": 0,
      "devicename": "server300",
      "objectName": "CPU",
      "data": [
        {
          "value":0.10,
          "rvalue":null
        },
        {
          "value":0.20,
          "rvalue":null
        },
        {
          "value": 0.25,
          "rvalue":null
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "timeRanges": [
    {
      "name":"1st Month",
      "startTime":1680000000,
      "endTime": 1689000000
    },
    {
      "name":"2nd Month",
      "startTime": 1680000000,
      "endTime": 1689000000
    },
    {
      "name":"3rd Month",
      "startTime": 1680000000,
      "endTime": 1689000000 
    }
  ]
}
'''

data = json.loads(json_data)


result = data['result']
time_ranges = data['timeRanges']


new_df = [
    {
        'deviceid': item['deviceid'],
        'devicename': item['devicename'],
        'objectName': item['objectName'],
        '1stMonth': item['data'][0]['value'],
        '2ndMonth': item['data'][1]['value'],
        '3rdMonth': item['data'][2]['value'],
        'startTime': time_ranges[i]['startTime'],
        'endTime': time_ranges[i]['endTime']
    }
    for i, item in enumerate(result)
]


df = pd.DataFrame(new_df)


print(df)
```

if it's already in dictionary format you skip that `json.loads()` part

```
import pandas as pd

data ={
  "result": [
    {
      "deviceid": 33,
      "devicename": "server101",
      "objectName": "CPU",
      "data": [
        {
          "value":0.59,
          "rvalue":None
        },
        {
          "value":90,
          "rvalue":None
        },
        {
          "value": 85,
          "rvalue":None
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "deviceid": 30,
      "devicename": "server10",
      "objectName": "CPU",
      "data": [
        {
          "value":0.30,
          "rvalue":None
        },
        {
          "value":60,
          "rvalue":None
        },
        {
          "value": 79,
          "rvalue":None
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "deviceid": 0,
      "devicename": "server300",
      "objectName": "CPU",
      "data": [
        {
          "value":0.10,
          "rvalue":None
        },
        {
          "value":0.20,
          "rvalue":None
        },
        {
          "value": 0.25,
          "rvalue":None
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "timeRanges": [
    {
      "name":"1st Month",
      "startTime":1680000000,
      "endTime": 1689000000
    },
    {
      "name":"2nd Month",
      "startTime": 1680000000,
      "endTime": 1689000000
    },
    {
      "name":"3rd Month",
      "startTime": 1680000000,
      "endTime": 1689000000 
    }
  ]
}


result = data['result']
time_ranges = data['timeRanges']

new_data = [
    {
        'deviceid': item['deviceid'],
        'devicename': item['devicename'],
        'objectName': item['objectName'],
        '1stMonth': item['data'][0]['value'],
        '2ndMonth': item['data'][1]['value'],
        '3rdMonth': item['data'][2]['value'],
        'startTime': time_ranges[i]['startTime'],
        'endTime': time_ranges[i]['endTime']
    }
    for i, item in enumerate(result)
]

df = pd.DataFrame(new_data)
print(df)
```

Output

```
   deviceid deviceName objectName  1stMonth  2ndMonth  3rdMonth   startTime     endTime
0        33  server101        CPU      0.59      90.0     85.00  1680000000  1689000000
1        30   server10        CPU      0.30      60.0     79.00  1680000000  1689000000
2         0  server300        CPU      0.10       0.2      0.25  1680000000  1689000000
```

Note that I converted `null` to `None` in the second example. In the first one `json.loads()` converts `null` to `None` during the parsing.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a more Pythonic approach

```
data_dict = json.loads(json_data)

df = pd.DataFrame([
    {
        "deviceid": device["deviceid"],
        "deviceName": device["devicename"],
        "objectName": device["objectName"],
        "1stMonth": device["data"][0]["value"],
        "2ndMonth": device["data"][1]["value"],
        "3rdMonth": device["data"][2]["value"],
        "startTime": data_dict["timeRanges"][0]["startTime"],
        "endTime": data_dict["timeRanges"][0]["endTime"]
    } 
    for device in data_dict["result"]
])
```